Как проверить на существование таблицы в C#
у меня есть база данных Database1.
как проверить существование таблицы из этой базы данных, и если не существует то создать новую? Используя Dapper,System.Data.SqlClient
public bool CheckUserTable()
{
    
}


Можно через схему, см. например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/992088/240512

А зачем проверять? Создавайте запрос как для миграции CREATE IF NOT EXISTS ...
